# Background Tasks with local files

Tags: ios, swift, file-upload, download, background

The app I develop allows user to store chosen file in encrypted form inside app directory (local). Now, lets say user wants to open a big file (>1gb) that is stored inside app. This can take quite some time, as I have the file split into multiple ones and need to decrypt them. What would be the procedure to allow this to work even when the app is suspended? As it is somewhat similar to upload/download, would want to use `URLSession` in background, but it does not support local files. I guess I could be using `beginBackgroundTask`, but it has limited execution time and it would feel like a hack (if user returns to app, I again beginBackgroundTask and continue to do this until task completes). Any suggestions? To be clear - all tasks are started in foreground and I don't want to use scheduling, as user would like to get the file as soon as possible.

EDIT, some usecases to maybe clarify situation a bit:

My app allows storing user selected files inside app (no cloud) in encrypted form. If selected file is big (>1gb), this operation could take several minutes to complete so I would like to allow user to do other things on his device while my app is processing the file in background. I know that I could implement this with background scheduling to this at the later date, but lets consider another example - user wants to open the big encrypted file that is stored inside app. As the user expects the result as soon as possible, scheduling for later is out of the question.

Comment: You should research async/await. URLSession is not relevant here as you say since you are dealing with local files.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson what about async/await, lets my app to continue executing while the app is SUSPENDED (as in not in foreground)? Please re-read the question, I'm not talking about threading here.

Comment: Yes I misinterpreted the word "background" apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an obvious candidate for `beginBackgroundTask`. You had two concerns:

- Re “limited execution time,” that’s true, but does your task really require more than 30 seconds? (If you really need more than 30 seconds, then next logical candidate is `BGProcessingTask`, but I would hesitate to add that complexity if not needed.)
- Re “if user returns to app, I again `beginBackgroundTask`,” the obvious suggestion would be to simply keep track of whether the task has been in started, and not relaunch it unnecessarily. Personally, I would start it as soon as the use selects it, and before you begin the task, just keep track of whether they’ve already started it or not. But this `beginBackgroundTask` is *not* something you defer until the app leaves foreground state, but rather would start it as soon as the user taps on it.

Bottom line, I would recommend `beginBackgroundTask` if this will always take less than 30 seconds. If it might exceed that, then you may have to consider [`BGProcessingTask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgprocessingtask) of [BackgroundTasks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks) framework, which will give you more time, but puts you at the mercy of the OS as to when the task will run.

See [Choosing Background Strategies for Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/choosing_background_strategies_for_your_app). Also, IIRC, WWDC 2020 video [Background execution demystified](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10063) outlines these options.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I thought that might me the case. I read all of the resources, provided and some more, it's just that this is a very specific usecase and there are no API for this sadly. I edited question a bit, might make my usecase clearer if you want to take another look. Again, really grateful for your answer, your other answers really helped me with other background work specifics.

Comment: Sadly, in iOS, we are very seriously constrained re our options. Yeah, if it’s more than 30 sec, the BackgroundTask framework is your only alternative. And even that is limited to 5 min, IIRC. (The precise time-windows for all of these are poorly documented and subject to change.)